# Better way to refer to entries in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

As far as I know, firebase assigns automatically an unique ID to every new entry in the database. However - these ids are really long and not good looking.

Whats more - I have to refer to them somehow, so currently when Im doing a get request, e.g. to get one entry Im doing something like:

`/getEntry/L4Cu7UOENIivnB2bgt`

And it's fine, since user doesn't see it anyways.
**Hovewer**, when making routes to every entry in my app, again I have to refer to specific entry by it's id. So e.g. if Im on route of specified element, e.g.:

`http://myapp.com/users/L4Cu7UOENIivnB2bgt` - it doesn't look very well if not ugly. If I would make my db in e.g. SQL or NoSQL, I would be able to assign an id by myself so it would increase from `1` and so on.

**Q**: Am I able to change these long `id`'s somehow? It has to be fixable somehow... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can set your own unique key. Say you have unique usernames for each user then you can do

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userName).set({
    firstName: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
});
```

or you can create your own unique ids and use instead. But there is no auto incremental ids.

> Using set() overwrites data at the specified location, including any child nodes.